# Plotting Coordinate Lines Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot the co-ordinate lines of a co-ordinate system (e.g. Cartesian co-ords) using matplotlib.

Then I want to transform them using some linear transform (skew, scale, rotate, etc.), and I want to plot this transformed version of the system as well.

I am quite new to matplotlib and I have no idea as to how I could go about doing this. Any suggestions?

Something like this:

[image]

Doesn't have to be on the same plot as above, I just want to be able to plot the lines (and shapes and their transformed versions as well).

EDIT: If you instead have a MATLAB solution, I'll take that too.

Comment: Do you have any code so far? Do you want the actual plot axes to be displayed with a linear transform (more complicated) or just plot the transformed objects on the normal plot (easy, just apply the appropriate mathematical formula to the points)?

Comment: I want a grid of coordinate lines as well. I want to show how the 'space' is transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[user2539738's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39019448/812786) demonstrates how to draw a grid in a plot. The next step is applying a transform.  This is a mathematical operation which can be described as a function of the x and y coordinates. For example, a shear transform like your example images -

```
def my_transform(x, y):
    return (x+y/2, y)
```

With this in mind, you can plot the transformed grid. You simply have to calculate the new coordinates:

```
# Transformed grid
for x in xx:
    (x1, y1) = my_transform(x, min(yy))
    (x2, y2) = my_transform(x, max(yy))
    plt.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],color='r')
for y in yy:
    (x1, y1) = my_transform(min(xx), y)
    (x2, y2) = my_transform(max(xx), y)
    plt.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],color='r')
```

This plots the transformed grid in red. The first for loop plots what were the vertical lines of the grid (going from point `x, min(yy)` to `x, max(yy)`), and the second plots the horizontal lines. The transform function is applied to the original pairs of points to calculate the new endpoints of the transformed line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started on the right track

```
import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xx = range(10)
yy = range(10)
[plt.plot([x,x],[min(yy),max(yy)],color='k') for x in xx]
[plt.plot([min(xx),max(xx)],[y,y],color='k') for y in yy]
```